How to access an embedded controller registers from a kernel module
I have a platform based on an Intel CPU with a Microchip EC (Embedded Controller) (MEC152x).  I'm trying to write a kernel module that access the watchdog timer registers through the EMI (embedded memory interface) which gives access to the internal registers of the EC (from what I understand from the datasheet). EMI is accessible via eSPI and I manage to retrieve the value of the Base Addresse Register but then I can't read the EMI registers (reading always returns 0xFF).
Please, how can I manipulate Ce EC to configure its watchdog. Thank you
Expexted: Read EMI default values (0x00)
Result: Read values 0xFF

You should add the original details from your "staging ground" question, like the I/O port access.  It's not clear to me that the watchdog timer is not accessible from eSPI.  Also,  you must be using some custom processor board.  You should tell us that as well.

This device supports some registers through an I/O port, some through memory mapping, some through I2C and some through eSPI.  Do you have the ACPI BIOS or DeviceTree information that describes your hardware setup?

What "base address register" did you fetch?  The chip's internal RAM space (at 4000_0000) is probably mapped into your host processors memory.  Once you have the virtual address that maps to that space, you just need to add the offset.  So, 4000_0400 will be at X+0x400, where X is the virtual address of the register space.

Intel-based machines in 99% cases are supplied with an ACPI BIOS which should have a description for the EC, and respectively there is a driver in the OS. With all that, the EC driver is responsible to communicate with EC.

I have an ACPI BIOS. Basically, I find my EC on i/o port 0x2e. Then I enter the configuration mode, select the eSPI  logical device to read the base address of the EMI but I can't get anywhere and I don't think this is the right solution to access the watchdog registers. Also i think that my BIOS uses the UART of this EC in COM1 on port 0x3f8 (I came to this conclusion when I disabled this i/o port from my bios setting, I lost my serial console, so my BIOS knows how to access the EC registers!).

I don’t know how to check if the EC maps its internal RAM registers to my cpu address space and how to get it’s virtual address. I am looking to access the watchdog timer registers to control it. Do you have any suggestions please @TimRoberts ?

@0andriy my BIOS is a version of American Megatrends customised by my Board manufacturer and i can’t get more details bout how the EC or its OS drivers !

I don't want to be Negative Nellie, but unless one of the BIOS people can TELL you this, it's going to be touch.  You can do a dmesg > log and look through the logs to see if you can find where the device initializes itself; there should be a note in there.

You are not supposed to do anything with EC behind the driver's back! Otherwise at bare minimum it's racy, in more serious cases you may break the hardware and brick your board. As @TimRoberts said, do this if and only if BIOS / HW people confirmed that it's safe.

BIOS of course knows about HW, but EC may just provide UART, BIOS communicates with EC via eSPI bus. It's like ISA in modern world.

Thank you guys for your help, I'll try to contact the manufacturer of my card again to get more details and maybe give you some feedback if I manage to code my watchdog driver
